# Regex to match sentence with particular pattern

Tags: regex

I want to extract certain sentences from a bunch of sentences. These sentences have a particular pattern but my regex fails when it encounters and alphanumeric string: See below example test string

```
"""Dear User,
Slow movt is at placeA ( Ohio | Missourri ) : placeB all d way to placeC is a no go area. wetin dey happen ooo. cc ( 2014-11-19 06:30 PM ) //passes my regex
Slow movt is at PlaceD ( Denver | Houston ) : .3 50pm. placeE&gt &gt ketu b2b //t.co/a7wmlxo6eu ( 2014-11-19 03:51 PM ).//fails my regex but passes if I remove alphanumerals
Average blah blah blah  (a|b) //t.co/a7nmloo6eu ( 2014-11-13 03:16 PM ).// passes my regex if no alphanumerals
yours sincerely 
TL"""
```

This is what I have come up with in my Regex:

```
((Slow|Average|Fast)\D+).(\(\s?\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}\s[AP]M\s\)\.)
```

Any help rendered is highly appreciated. Please note I need to extract all matches, so the perfect solution for my above string will yield 3 matches excluding the `"Hi User"` and `"Your sincerely TL"` from the matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\D+` only matches non-digits, so it fails on `1pm`.

Can you simply match "anything"?

```
((Slow|Average|Fast).*)(\(\s?\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}\s[AP]M\s\)\.)
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/pE7lB9/2).

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for your input. The sentence structure is slightly more complex. Please see my edit above

Comment: OK, how about removing the restrictions on what may match entirely?

Comment: Hi Tim, Thank you for your time. It was a bit difficult recreating the problem in the public domain. I thought I posted what was representative. I have edited again... My bad and I am sorry, just cannot post the exact contents of the document. Thanks once again

Comment: Your edited text matches all three examples with the regex if you remove the `\.` from the end (since it doesn't appear to be mandatory).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your currently stated requirements

```
((Slow|Average|Fast).+)(\(\s?\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}\s[AP]M\s\)\.?)
```

does work: [RegEx101](http://regex101.com/r/mB8nG5/2).

If you have more restrictions to meet, please, comment.